# XMPP client cannot connect to gtalk server in Android

Tags: android, xmpp, android-logcat

I am using XMPP example from [this](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/) address. I am putting the following configuration in setup for XMMP client

```
Host     gtalk.google.com port 5222
Service  gmail.com
```

But it is unable to connect to gatlk server. I am getting the following exception:

```
02-09 E/AndroidRuntime(301): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-09 22:16:15.541: D/dalvikvm(301): GC freed 6905 objects / 312000 bytes in 102ms
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:329)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:301)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:283)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at org.apache.android.xmpp.SettingsDialog.onClick(SettingsDialog.java:54)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:643)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-09 22:16:15.541: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 22:16:15.561: I/dalvikvm(301): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-09 22:16:15.821: I/dalvikvm(301): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: try to change folder lib into libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u tried "talk.google.com" as the host name. 
http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html

Comment: Thnks Buddy.Now I am able to run XMPP Client on Emulator.I am stuck with another problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469899/certificate-parser-in-android.I hope you can help me on this.