# Certificate Parser in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-logcat

I wonder if I am missing some piece of code in this example.I am getting compile-time error on  certHeader,certFooter in this class.IF someone can give me a brief idea about it that will be helpful.or IF some one has a better example on certificate parser that will be helpful.
I am using this example to parse a certificate.

```
try 
{ 
    String abc = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + "ALneIwerZ5Nu+z1Yjvdco9sOHfkhYW4nL+FIlGDGIS +YsyevB8YN2hBnog7gtQ6PB+sVF6o/1UdU\n" + // lines deleted for brevity "rchFUEChHZ5G7AAk02K7/iyqITc/IPNHHpilTg/NB6QhF9s=\n" + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

int headerIndex = abc.indexOf(certHeader); 
    if (headerIndex == -1) 
    {
        throw new CertificateParsingException("cannot find BEGIN CERTIFICATE");
        }
    int startIndex = headerIndex + certHeader.length();

int endIndex = abc.indexOf(certFooter);
if (endIndex == -1) 
{
    throw new CertificateParsingException("cannot find END CERTIFICATE"); }

String cert = abc.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
byte[] certBytes = cert.getBytes();

InputStream in = new Base64InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes));

CertificateFactory certFact = CertificateFactory.getInstance ("X.509");
Certificate certGen = certFact.generateCertificate(in);
X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate)
certGen; 
}
catch (Exception e) 
{ 
    Log.e("testapp", "exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`certHeader` and `certFooter` are supposed to be int variables. From what you've shown us, it doesn't look like you've declared them anywhere.

From the [String.indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) documentation:

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified character. If a character with value ch occurs in the
>   character sequence represented by this String object, then the index
>   (in Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is returned. For
>   values of ch in the range from 0 to 0xFFFF (inclusive), this is the
>   smallest value k such that:
>
> ```
> this.charAt(k) == ch
> ```

Comment: Thanku Marvin.Again I am getting some compile time error on certHeader.length(); (Cannot invoke length() on the primitive type int).If you have implemented certificate parser before you can give me the link.Because I think I will have some other errors in this program.

Comment: @saurabhverma I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with `certHeader.length()`. Assuming you've already declared `certHeader` as the appropriate int value of the _char_ you are looking for, and you have the index of that char in `headerIndex`, what did you need `certHeader.length` for?

Comment: Marvin even I have copied this piece of code from http://markmail.org/message/ppykrk2mhq5pediq.Even I am trying to understand how this code will return me certificate details.

Comment: Marvin If you come up with some good example or able to implement this example to get certificate details please let me know.